# Vue JS make an array reactive

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to build a forum front end with Vue.

One of the functionalities i´ts add new answers to a specific question.

First of all I make a GET HTTP Request to the server to display the current post and the answers if it had some.

Then if a user post a new answer I make a POST HTTP Request to the server and then in the response I just push this new item in the 'answers' array defined in data()

Form when the event is handled

```
  <form v-if="editorVisible" @submit.prevent="handleNewComment">
      <vue-editor v-model="answer.text" :editorToolbar="customToolbar"></vue-editor>

      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-2">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark">
          <span>Add comment</span>
        </button>
        <button @click.prevent="editorVisible = false" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger ml-3">
          <span>Cancel</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

HTML and Vue code where data is rendered

```
        <div class="ml-3 mt-4" v-if="this.answers.length > 0">
      <h5>Answers {{answers.length}}</h5>
      <div v-for="(item,index) in answers" :key="index">
        <hr />
        <div v-html="item.text"></div>

        <div id="post-menu" class="d-flex p-2 ml-4 mt-3">
          <div
            v-if="(currentUser.id === comment.author.id || currentUser.id === item.author.id)  && editorVisible === false"
          >
            <router-link
              :to="{ name: 'editAnswer', params: { commentId: item.id, parentId: comment.id}}"
            >Edit</router-link>

            <a class="ml-2" v-on:click="handleDeleteAnswer(item.id)">Delete</a>
          </div>

          <div
            class="user-information d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-start align-items-center rounded ml-auto m-2 p-2 bg-light"
          >
            <span
              class="user-action-time text-muted pb-2 w-100"
            >answered {{item.posted | completeDate}}</span>
            <b-avatar variant="dark" text rounded size="2.2em">
              <span
                id="userNameAbbreviation"
              >{{ item.author.username | getUserNameAbbreviation}}</span>
            </b-avatar>
            <span
              id="username"
              class="align-self-start text-muted ml-2"
            >{{item.author.username}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Vue JS code

```
export default {
props: ["commentId"],
components: {
   VueEditor
},
data() {
   return {
      comment: new Comment("", ""),
      answer: new Comment("", "", ""),
      answers: [],
      message: "",
      editorVisible: false,
      customToolbar: [
      [{ header: [false, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }],
      ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"], // toggled buttons
      ["blockquote", "code-block"],
      [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
      [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }], // dropdown with defaults from theme
      ["link"],
      ["clean"] // remove formatting button
     ]
   };
 },
 methods: {
    handleDeleteComment() {
    CommentService.delete(this.comment.id).then(
       response => {
          this.message = response.data;
          console.log(this.message);
          this.$router.push("/");
       },
       error => {
         this.message =
         (error.response && error.response.data) ||
         error.message ||
         error.toString();
         console.log(this.message);
    }
  );
},
handleDeleteAnswer: function(answer_id) {
  CommentService.delete(answer_id).then(
    response => {
      this.message = response.data;
      console.log(this.message);
      this.$router.push("/comments/" + this.commentId);
    },
    error => {
      this.message =
        (error.response && error.response.data) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      console.log(this.message);
    }
  );
},
handleNewComment() {
  this.answer.parent_id = this.comment.id;
  this.answer.title = this.comment.id;
  CommentService.ask(this.answer).then(
    response => {
      this.message = response.data;
      this.answers.push(this.answer);
      console.log(this.message);
    },
    error => {
      this.message =
        (error.response && error.response.data) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      console.log(this.message);
    }
  );
}
  },
  mounted() {
CommentService.get(this.commentId).then(
  response => {
    this.comment = response.data;
    console.log(this.comment);
    document.title = "Comment | details";
    this.dataLoaded = true;
  },
  error => {
    this.message =
      (error.response && error.response.data) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString();
    console.log(this.message);
  }
);
CommentService.getThread(this.commentId).then(
  response => {
    this.answers = response.data;

    console.log(this.answers);
  },
  error => {
    this.message =
      (error.response && error.response.data) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString();
    console.log(this.message);
  }
);
 },
 computed: {
currentUser() {
  return this.$store.state.auth.user;
}
},
filters: {
shortDate: function(date) {
  return moment(date)
    .local()
    .fromNow();
},
completeDate: function(date) {
  return moment(date).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm");
},
getUserNameAbbreviation: function(username) {
  return username.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
}
}
};
```

The problem it´s when I push a new element to the array Vue.js isnt detecting that change in the array and render the new element in the v-for directive.

Thank you all :)

Comment: Using `arr.push()` should result in working reactivity. If you would be setting an index you would have to use `this.$set(arr, 1, 'myvalue')`. Also you should not have to use the `function` keyword. I cant see any obvious issue though.

Comment: Thanks, that what I been reading in the Vue official documentation, but I doens´t work and is weird. Thanks for your advices I use de function keyword when I must pass some arguments to the method. Also this.$set(arr, 1, 'myvalue') still not working, setting array index like: (this.anwers.lenght + 1)

Comment: You can just use `handleDeleteAnswer(answer_id) { ... }`. I suggest to create  a simple testcase by either disabling most of the functions this component does, or creating a new array `testArray: []` and do some tests with that.

Comment: First the problem was I wasn't updating the index and then in the correct way. Thank you so much.

Comment: `.push()` should just work. You are potentially hiding another issue by just using `this.$set` now

Comment: `.push` is working fine too. Push in the answers an incomplete anwer object was a mistake, now my backend is returning the filled object in the response and not just a http status, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
handleNewComment() {
  this.answer.parent_id = this.comment.id;
  this.answer.title = this.comment.id;

  CommentService.ask(this.answer).then(
    response => {
      this.message = response.data;
      this.editorVisible = false;
      this.$set(this.answers, this.answers.length, this.message);
      console.log(this.message);
    },
    error => {
      this.message =
        (error.response && error.response.data) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      console.log(this.message);
    }
  );
}
```

Just updating the index in the proper way Vue.js finally could mutate de array.